# ¿Cómo debo ingresar los datos a Rstudio para hacer un análisis de densidad o home range con Kernel?

Tags: r

¿Cómo debo ingresar los datos a `Rstudio` para hacer un análisis de densidad o `home range` con `Kernel`? En algún lugar, dice que deben ser coordenadas UTM, pero no se exactamente a donde debo ingresar para esto.

Answer (score 1):

Según el **[manual (página 4)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatHR/vignettes/adehabitatHR.pdf)**, puedes usar dos clases de objetos:

1. ***SpatialPoints***
2. ***SpatialPointsDataFrame***

Ambas clases dentro del [paquete sp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html). En la mísma página dan un pequeño ejemplo del cómo convertir a las clases indicadas:

```
#genera una matriz de en forma aleatoria
xy <- matrix(runif(60), ncol=2) 

#en este punto es donde hace el cambio de clase.
xysp <- SpatialPoints(xy)
```

Te recomiendo revisar toda la documentación, pues contiene ejemplos reproducibles. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! intentare hacerlo.

Comment: Excelente nos comentas tus resultados